# df.apply returning errors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to do a Vlookup / true test to populate a value based upon a range.  I am using `df.apply` as a means to this end.  The `Width` column is float64.

Definition:

```
def f(x):
    if ['Width'] < 66: return 'DblStk'
    elif ['Width'] >= 66 & ['Width'] <= 77: return 'DblStkHC'
    elif ['Width'] >= 77 & ['Width'] <= 92: return 'RbBase'
    elif ['Width'] >= 92 & ['Width'] <= 94: return 'RBBildge'
    elif ['Width'] >= 94: return 'StdOnly'
    else: return 0

df_filtered['RollCat'] = df_filtered.apply(f,axis=1)
```

I am receiving a type error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [53], in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 df_filtered['RollCat'] = df_filtered.apply(f,axis=1)
>
> File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:8839, in
> DataFrame.apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwargs)
> 8828 from pandas.core.apply import frame_apply    8830 op =
> frame_apply(    8831     self,    8832     func=func,    (...)    8837
> kwargs=kwargs,    8838 )
> -> 8839 return op.apply().**finalize**(self, method="apply")

Appreciate any guidance or help.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `df.apply()` with the argument `axis=1`, the function you pass as an argument is applied to each row of the dataframe. That means that within the function it is a Pandas Series object.

If your function `f(x)`, you are comparing a list (`['Width']`) to a number, which doesn't make sense. If there is a column of your dataframe called "Width" containing float values, then you should be able to do:

```
def f(x):
    # Now we are inside the function so 'x' is a Pandas Series object
    width = x['Width']    # Now, the variable called 'width' is a float
    if width < 66:
        ...
```

Note that we have to actually retrieve the float value of the "Width" column for the row of interest. If you simply do `['Width']` then this is just a plain Python list and not a float, and therefore can't be compared to a numeric value.

Also in general, for joining Python conditions use `and` instead of `&`. And when you provide a traceback, make sure you provide the full error message. My guess is your error message says something like `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'`, but it is always helpful to provide this information rather than just a traceback that points to where the error occurs but does not say what it is.

Comment: It's too broad to say `df.apply()` works on rows. Only `df.apply(axis=1)` works on rows. By default it operates by columns.

Comment: This is a good point. I have edited the original answer for clarity. But yes, as formulated by the OP it will work on rows, but without `axis=1` it will work on columns instead.

Comment: Thanks tdy. I am still working this example. I appreciate the insight and feedback.

Comment: I'm getting closer, incorporating everyone's feedback.  'df_filtered.apply(f,axis=1)' returns the information I am looking for.  Assigning to a new column generates an .loc error.  'df_filtered['RollCat'] = df_filtered.apply(f,axis=1)'.  **bold** A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead **bold**

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df_filtered['RollCat'] = df_filtered.apply(f,axis=1)**bold

Comment: Adding result_type='broadcast' achieved the final results I was looking for, new column added in the original dataframe